# Highcharts Sunburst levels radius

Tags: highcharts, dotnethighcharts

I'm making a sunburst with Highcharts .NET,

This is how i setup the chart:

```
Highcharts higcharts = new Highcharts
{
    Chart = new Chart
    {
        Type = ChartType.Sunburst,
        Width = 700,
        Height = 700
    },
    Title = new Title
    {
        Text = "Monthly Average Temperature",
        X = -20
    },
    Subtitle = new Subtitle
    {
        Text = "Source: WorldClimate.com",
        X = -20
    },
    Legend = new Legend
    {
        Layout = LegendLayout.Vertical,
        Align = LegendAlign.Right,
        VerticalAlign = LegendVerticalAlign.Middle,
        BorderWidth = 0
    },
    Series = new List<Series>
{
    new SunburstSeries
    {
        Name ="Test",
        Data = data,
        //LevelSize = new SunburstSeriesLevelSize
        //{
        //    Unit = SunburstSeriesLevelSizeUnit.Percentage,
        //    Value = 100
        //},
        Levels = new List<SunburstSeriesLevels>
        {
            new SunburstSeriesLevels
            {
                LevelSize = new SunburstSeriesLevelsLevelSize{
                    Unit = SunburstSeriesLevelsLevelSizeUnit.Percentage,
                    Value = 90
                }
            },
            new SunburstSeriesLevels
            {
                LevelSize = new SunburstSeriesLevelsLevelSize{
                    Unit = SunburstSeriesLevelsLevelSizeUnit.Percentage,
                    Value = 10
                }
            }
        }
       }
    }
};
```

I tried many ways but the levels radius never change, did i miss something?

The only one working is the levelsize of the entire serie but i need to set the size for a specific level.

I tried to search but it looks like nobody already encountered any problem.

Answer (score 0):

Level's object `levelSize` is able do control the size of individual level. It has two properties: `unit` (`pixels` / `percentage` / `weight`) and `value` (determined by the unit):

```
    levels: [{
        level: 1,
        levelIsConstant: false,
        levelSize: {
            unit: 'pixels',
            value: 30
        }
    }, {
        level: 2,
        colorByPoint: true,
        dataLabels: {
            rotationMode: 'parallel'
        }
    }, {
        level: 3,
        levelIsConstant: true,
        levelSize: {
            unit: 'weight',
            value: 2
        }
    }, {
        level: 4,
        levelIsConstant: true,
        levelSize: {
            unit: 'percentage',
            value: 30
        }
    }]
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/plotoptions/sunburst-levelsize/

**API reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.sunburst.levelSize